# How to power STM32F411CE with 18650 Batteries

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, stm32

I am looking to power the STM32F411CE with 2 18650 batteries. I am regulating voltage down to 5 V from the batteries currently.

I want to know if I can power the board by connecting my 5 V line directly to the 5 V pin on the board shown below:

[image]

I have read through datasheets but I am still confused. The boards' datasheet states that the board can have a max voltage input of 3.6 V. However, I found this source that states the board has a regulator that can support up to 5.25 V.

[image]

From my research I found a few sources saying that the 5 V pins are only for when the board is being powered via USB. Is this this true?

And if the board can only be powered via 3.3 V from battery which pin(s) would I connect to my stepped down voltage line of 3.3 V?

[Datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f411ce.html)
[Application Note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4488-getting-started-with-stm32f4xxxx-mcu-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: Please link to the datasheet and any other documentation you have. We can't tell from a couple of images.

Comment: Datasheet: https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f411ce.html

Application Note: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4488-getting-started-with-stm32f4xxxx-mcu-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Are you confusing the datasheet of the microcontroller (the STM32F411) with the datasheet of the board it's soldered to (which also apparently contains a voltage regulator, as well as a USB socket and some buttons)?

Comment: Yes, I think I am. I'm not sure how to find the datasheet for the board itself though (Black Pill). After some googling I came up with nothing. I linked the datasheet that I have been using above.

Answer (score 3):

STM32 microcontrollers work from 3.3V, but you need to check the board schematic of this specific board. It probably has 5V->3.3V regulator, so that you can power it from USB (99% chance that it does, would be weird if you couldn't power it from USB). But what exactly the nature of that 5V is doesn't really matter. I mean, if it's 5V input, how is it supposed to know if it's 5V from USB or lab power supply or batteries. 5V is 5V.

So check the board schematic, not microcontroller datasheet, find the linear regulator that's most likely there (you should be able to find it on the other side of the board, not shown in the image), then check in the schematic how that 5V pin is wired to it. If it's connected directly to USB 5V and feeds the linear 3.3V regulator, you're good to supply it with 5V. That's what I would expect.

The closest schematic (black pill, [source](https://innovatorsguru.com/stm32-black-pill/)):

[image]

Apologies for low quality, it's the best applicable schematic I could google up.

Notice here we have PB11 instead of your 5V pin (on JP4), so there is a small difference. Take a multimeter, beep 5V to the diode on the top side and to the USB 5V pin. If it beeps, you're good to power it with 5V via the pin.

Comment: So in the case that the 5v->3.3v regulator is present. I would connect my 5v line to the 5v pin on the board?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Still, find board schematic.

Comment: This is the closest I could find. The board is called "Black Pill" (edited in)

Comment: I found the proper schematic. https://stm32-base.org/assets/pdf/boards/original-schematic-STM32F411CEU6_WeAct_Black_Pill_V2.0.pdf

Comment: @KyleClose USB 5V and 5V pin are the very same line on the schematic. You're free to apply 5V to it, but only as long as USB is not connected. Never connect 2 power sources together, even if they have the same voltage.

Comment: If you want to connect USB and 5V pin at the same time, connect battery 5V to 5V pin through the diode.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help.